Azure SQL database backup?
I have configured Azure SQL database to be backed up.
I have a database that resides in the North Central US region, and this database is backed up to a different location.
How can I find out from Azure the location this backup is stored in?
I've tried the portal but can't seem to find any details

Azure SQL databases use geo-redundant backups that are automatically replicated to the region paired with the primary region of your database. You can find the list of Azure region pairs in Microsoft's documentation: Azure Paired Regions.
In the Overview section of your Azure SQL Database in Azure Portal, you will find the current location of your database. The geo-replicated backup will be in the paired region of that location.

